# JavaScript global variable 'undefined' when working with external js file

Tags: javascript, html, eclipse

I'm currently making a Design Studio custom component in Eclipse. One of the things I have to do is make my dropdown lists adjustable in my additional properties pane. So in my 'additional_properties_sheet.html' I have the following code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Annotation property sheet</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <script src="/somepath/sdk_propertysheets_handler.js"></script>
        <script src="../js/component.js"></script>
        
        <script src="additional_properties_sheet.js"></script>
        <script></script>
    </head>
    <script>
        new com.sap.sample.annotation.AnnotationPropertyPage();
    </script>
    <body>
        <form id="form">
        
        <button type="button" onclick="test()">Click me</button>
        
            
        </form>
        
    </body>
    
</html>
```

And in my js file 'component.js I have something similar to this code:

```
var retrieveObj;
define(["sap/designstudio/sdk/component", "d3", "../js/ckeditor/ckeditor", "css!../css/component.css"], function(Component, d3, ckeditor, css) {
Component.subclass("com.sap.sample.annotation.Annotation", function() {

var me = this;

me.redraw = function(){
//have some code before here to add some layout and stuff

    //they wated some delay on the dropdowns
    var myVar = setTimeout(myTimer, 2000);
    function myTimer() {
        //thediagram is a rectangle to which I add this dropdown
        commObjDropdown = theDiagram.append("foreignObject")
        .attr("x", "5%")
        .attr("y", "76%")
        .attr("width", "226")
        .attr("height", "30")
        .append("xhtml:body")
        .html('<select name="commObjs" id="commObjs" class="commObjs"></select>');
        
        
        retrieveObj=document.getElementById("commOjbs");
        //this alert gives me the object
        alert(retrieveObj);

    }
}

me.init = function() {
        //me.getCalls();
        me.redraw();
        //me.createEditor();
        };

});

function test(){
//here the alert gives me 'undefined'
alert(retrieveObj);
}
```

Every time I click the button it returns 'undefined'. I need a way to retrieve my dropdown object so I can adjust it in the additional property pane anyone knows a way out?

Comment: i am unable to see jQuery base library added before your  other jaavscript/jQuery files ? do you have that or not?

Comment: Is your `me.redraw` getting called?

Comment: Is your `me.init` getting called?

Comment: @AlivetoDie no I do not have that currently, do I need it for anything?

Comment: @Rajesh all my functions are called correctly and work just fine

Comment: @mrdeadsven you tagged this with jQuery, but I don't see you using jQuery anywhere.

Comment: Are you waiting for everything to complete before clicking the test button? Until all of the call back functions are completed, **retrieveObj** will be undefined.